Booking Flights and Hotels Through an Acquaintance – Is It a Problem?
I am an Indian passport holder planning to travel to Japan. I would like to know if my tourist visa application could be negatively affected if my travel tickets and hotel bookings are made by an acquaintance instead of through my own account.
Specifically, will the visa authorities find it unusual if the expenses do not appear on the bank statements I have provided? Could this raise doubts about the authenticity of the bookings?
I do have a sufficient bank balance, but since my acquaintance has better credit card offers, I am considering booking the flights and hotels through him.

What is your relationship with this “acquaintance”? Partner? Parent? What’s in it for them? Are you going to repay them? Are you aware that you might loose the benefit of travel insurance bundled with the card? That in some circumstances you may have to show the card at the airport before you are allowed to check-in?

I will repay them if need be, in future

to be honest, they are a very close friend of mine

Is the friend traveling with you?

If two people are traveling together and sharing accommodations, any given accommodation will be booked and paid for by only one of the travelers.
It certainly can't be a reason for automatic refusal.

Specifically, will the visa authorities find it unusual if the expenses do not appear on the bank statements I have provided? Could this raise doubts about the authenticity of the bookings?

Very unlikely.  You can mention that your friend paid.  If you are reimbursing your friend, do it soon enough that it is reflected on the statement you submit with the application, which will provide a perfect opportunity for that explanation.

This may depend on whether the friend is traveling with OP or just booking the accommodation for them and getting paid cash rather than by bank transfer.
